# application of Borel functional calculus

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose for any postive operator $T \in B(H) $,we have a real bounded Borel function $f_{T}$ on $\sigma(T)$.

If we have a non-trivial projection $P$on a Hilbert space $H$ and $k>0$.Let $P^{\perp}=1-P$ .$f$ is a real bounded borel functional on $\sigma(kP+P^{\perp})$,how to show that there exist two functions $g_P,h_P:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ such that $f(kP+P^{\perp})=g_P(k)P+h_P(k)P^{\perp}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spectrum of $kP+P^\perp$ is $\{1,k\}$, so the spectral measure is given by $E(\{k\})=P$, $E(\{1\})=P^\perp$. So, for any Borel function $f$, 
$$
f(kP+P^\perp)=\int_{\{1,k\}} f(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda)=f(1)P^\perp+f(k)P. 
$$

Comment: If $N$ is a normal operator, $N=\int_{\{1,k\}} \iota(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda)$,where $\iota(\lambda)=\lambda$,then we have $kE(\{k\})+E(\{1\})=kP+P^{\perp}$,we cannot conclude that $E(\{k\})=P,E(\{1\})=P^{\perp}.$

Comment: What's the spectral measure then, according to you?

Comment: But how to derive    $E(\{k\})=P,E(\{1\})=P^{\perp}. $ from     $kE(\{k\})+E(\{1\})=kP+P^{\perp}$?

Comment: $E(\{k\})=1_{\{k\}}(kP+P^\perp)$. Since the spectrum is discrete, any function is continuous; so $1_{\{k\}}$ is equal to any polynomial $f$ with $f(k)=1$, $f(1)=0$. Then $$1_{\{k\}}(kP+P^\perp)=f(kP+P^\perp)=f(k)P+f(1)P^\perp=P.$$

Comment: You mean $f$ is polynomial which is  defined on $\sigma(kP+P^{\perp})$?

Comment: You make it sound too complicated. The set $\sigma(kP+P^\perp)$ consists of the two numbers $k$ and $1$. Any real polynomial is defined on any set of real numbers.